# Sorting ArrayList by comparator

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I have an ArrayList containing CoolMove elements and want to sort it by the values CoolMove.getValue() returns (these values are Doubles). I read that you can sort using a comparator class and in an attempt to do this I made the following:

I have 2 classes, one having these code lines:

```
ArrayList<CoolMove> moveList = getMoves();
Arrays.sort(fishMoves, new myComp());
```

My 2nd class is this comparator:

```
class myComp implements Comparator<CoolMove> {

    @Override
    public int compare(CoolMove move1, CoolMove move2) {
        return Double.compare(move1.getValue(), move2.getValue());
    }
}
```

My problem is that at Arrays.sort I get this error:
The method sort(T[], Comparator) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList, myComp)
How can I fix this?

Comment: You need `Collections.sort()` rather than `Arrays.sort()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moveList` is a list not an array, use the sort method from `Collections`:

```
Collections.sort(moveList, new myComp());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify all of it using [`List.sort​(Comparator<? super E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator))as:

```
moveList.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(CoolMove::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list (JDK 8.0)

```
moveList.sort(new myComp());
```

Comment: worth saying, this is only available as of JDK8